# How to install camera module ribbon?

Tags: camera, pi-zero, cable, tutorial

I want to install a zero-compatible camera ribbon on my camera module. However, I am unsure of how to remove the cable. It doesn't come out easily and I don't want to force it. Is there any guide on how to remove/attach the ribbon from the camera module?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFAX4pH1BPA

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, old but unanswered.  The connector has a latching mechanism, on mine the connector body is light colored, the latch is dark.  On a Zero pull the latch away from the main part of the board, on a Pi pull it up.  It only moves about 1/16 inch (1.5 mm).   The cable should practically fall out of the slot after it's unlatched.  I don't think it does any major harm to force it without unlatching first but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Also the Zero end of the cable (narrow) should be inserted so that the stiffener (the thin piece of plastic on the side of the cable opposite the bare contacts) is inserted facing the top (component) side of the Zero. On the pi camera end of the cable (wide) the stiffener should be inserted facing away from the camera side of the board.